# insert function PHP mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-insert

I have a function in PHP mySQL that inserts records into a database.  It take in an array of decoded JSON data, a field name, a connection and a DB name.  It then builds a SQL statement and inserts the records one by one, or at least thats what I think it should do.  I run everything, make the connection, database and table but when it gets to this function, it fails.  I feel it has to do with my INSERT statement but I am not sure how to fix it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Function:

```
function insertRecords($array,$fieldname, $conn, $db_NAME)
{
    mysqli_select_db($conn, $db_NAME);

    $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO `tbl_articles` (`" . $fieldname . "`) VALUES ('" . $records . "')";

    foreach ($array as $records)
    {

        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql_insert))
        {
            echo "Records Inserted.";
        }
        else 
        {
            die('Error : ' . mysqli_error($conn) . "<br>");
        }
    }
    echo $sql_insert . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: You're using `$records` when you create your INSERT, before you define it.

Comment: I think the query string must be in the foreach block.

Comment: put your insert in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just looks like that your query string is displaced there. Just try this:

```
function insertRecords($array,$fieldname, $conn, $db_NAME){
    mysqli_select_db($conn, $db_NAME);

    foreach ($array as $records)
    {
        $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO `tbl_articles` (`" . $fieldname . "`) VALUES ('" . $records . "')";
        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql_insert))
        {
            echo "Records Inserted.";
        }
        else 
        {
            die('Error : ' . mysqli_error($conn) . "<br>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked but it still does not insert anything into the database... the table it built with the correct fields but no records are inserted... why would this be?

Comment: What are the queries (from echo)? Do you can execute them manually via phpMyAdmin or something like this?

Comment: I just had that in there to debug.  I forgot to take it out.

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, but if it does not work, you have to debug it ;-)

Comment: Yeah I am trying. I tried putting that same echo statement inside the foreach loop but it doesn't output anything.  Its as if the insert function is never being run.  Yet I call it twice in my index file.